# Java Convert XML to bytearray, split, send through Websphere MQ and merge

Tags: java, xml, spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We need to upload and process XML files. I convert them to bytearray and send through Websphere MQ/Spring JMS and process the file in the backend application server. The Websphere MQ has a message size limit of 2MB. We don't have control over that. Please recommend an efficient way to split the file/bytearray and have them assembled/merged in the datazone.

Is it easy to split the XML and pass chunks of XML data as bytearray. Examples/sample code would be fantastic. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Default size of message in IBM MQ is 4 MB and maximum message size is 100 MB. I think in your configuration you have limited the message size to 2 MB?

Comment: @Shashi Again not my config or under my control. It's external and we need to work with that limit. Thanks

Comment: Compress them too, like with a GZipOutputStream.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026360_.htm

You should be able to use the flag `MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED` and `MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG` which lets the MQ API split and reassemble large messages.

However, it's not supported by all platforms, in which case you have to do that programmatically using the the `GroupId`,`MsgSeqNumber`,`Offset` and `OriginalLength` MQMD fields.

Comment: Thank you. Can this be done through Spring-JMS. Please let know.